# Conflict between Roboto and DejaVuSans

Tags: fonts

In a document, i load both `Roboto` and `DejaVuSans` packages (in this order) to set DejaVuSans as the default sans serif family and to have access to commands like `\roboto` or `\robotocondensed` defined in the `Roboto` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{roboto}
\usepackage{DejaVuSans}

\begin{document}
{\sffamily\bfseries No bold here ! :-(}
\end{document}
```

But i don't get bold typeface with `\sffamily\bfseries`.
I suppose it's because of the use of `mweights` package by `Roboto` (or because `DejaVuSans` doesn't use `mweights` ...).

Is there a workaround to have both packages loaded and working at the same time ?

Comment: If you get no bold then there must be a warning in your log file for a missing font. Show these lines of your log. And, of course, what engine are you running.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the reason for mixing Roboto and DejaVuSans.

Comment: @Red-Cloud I have no missing font. If you test my mwe you'll get no bold because (i think) `mweights` re-defines standard selection commands for series and families.

@egreg My document uses only DejaVuSans but i need Roboto for pictures with a special design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imho it is easier to define the commands directly than to fight against the settings of the roboto package. E.g. for pdflatex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{DejaVuSans}
\newcommand\roboto{\fontfamily{Roboto-LF}\selectfont}
\newcommand*\robotocondensed{\roboto\fontseries{c}\selectfont}
\begin{document}
{\sffamily\bfseries No bold here ! :-(} {\sffamily and normal text}

{\roboto some text in \bfseries roboto}

{\robotocondensed some text in \bfseries condensed}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, it seems to be the easiest way to have both fonts even if it's a bit annoying the two packages can't work together...